# Linq Contains and Distinct

Tags: linq, join, contains

I have the following 3 tables with their fields

**Books**(Id_Book | Title | Year) 
**Book_Themes** (Id | Id_Book| Id_Theme)
**Themes** (Id_Theme| Title)

I also have an Giud array with Id_Themes

```
Guid [] themesArray = new Guid []{new Guid("6236c491-b4ae-4a2f-819e-06a38bf2cf41"), new Guid("06586887-7e3f-4f0a-bb17-40c86bfa76ce")};
```

I'm trying to get all **Books** containing any of the **Theme_Ids** from the **themesArray**

This is what I have so far which is not working. Not sure how to use Contains in this scnenario.

```
int index = 1; int size= 10;
var books = (from book in DB.Books
               join bookWThemes in DB.Book_Themes
               on book.Id_Book equals bookWThemes.Id_Book

               where themesArray.Contains(bookWThemes.Id_Theme)                           
               orderby book.Year
               select book)
               .Skip((index - 1) * page)
               .Take(size);
```

I'm getting an error on themesArray.Contains(bookWThemes.Id_Theme): System.Guid[] does not contain a definition for Contains. Also I'm not sure where to put the Distinct

*************UPDATE*************

noticed that my Model had Id_Theme as nullable... I changed the DB and didn't reflect the changes on my model. So to answer the question if it's nullable just change the Contains line to themesArray.Contains(bookWThemes.Id_Theme.Value)... and with this change it works.

Thanks for all the help!.

Comment: Is this a compile time error?

Comment: Linq to Entities or Linq to SQL?

Comment: yes it's a compile time error

Comment: this is Linq to Entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange that your LINQ query is breaking down on .Contains.  All three of the forms IEnumerable<> and List<> work for me.

```
    [Test]
    public void Test43()
    {
        var a = new List<Guid>(){new Guid(),new Guid(),new Guid()};
        a.Contains(new Guid());  // works okay
        var b = (IEnumerable<Guid>)a;
        b.Contains<Guid>(new Guid()); // works okay
        b.Contains(new Guid()); // works okay 
    }
```

Comment: thanks man... it's working now. actually I noticed that and updated my DB and Model... but it seems the change didn't reflect on my model. So if it's nullable just used this where themesArray.Contains(bookWThemes.Id_Theme.Value)... I'm just fixing my model

Answer (score 0):

For the "distinct" question, put the call here:

```
           select book)
           .Distinct()  // <--
           .Skip((index - 1) * page)
```

Comment: thanks cdhowie, the question is more about how to use the Contains... Just edited the question to reflect this

Comment: I just figured out the Contains section... now for the Distinct. I put the Distinct just like you advised and I got this message - The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: Oops, I guess you can't throw the `Distinct()` call there -- you need to insert it before the `orderby`.  See [this article](http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/07/20/use-of-distinct-and-orderby-in-linq.aspx).

Comment: just working on this, but getting the same error. I guess I'll post another question just for the Distinct piece, as this post was more about the Contains clause... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the `Guid[]` to `List<Guid>` and then you can use Contains on it.

```
where themesArray.ToList().Contains(bookWThemes.Id_Theme)
```

Comment: got a couple of compile errors. 1. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Guid>.Contains(System.Guid)' has some invalid argument. 2.cannot convert from 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'

Comment: ok this is what I did to solve it - where themesArray.Contains(bookWThemes.Id_Theme.Value)

Comment: @Rodrigo: That means that your `Id_Theme` property is nullable in your data model. Without you posting what your entities look like exactly nobody could have known

Comment: actually I noticed that and updated my DB and Model... but it seems the change didn't reflect on my model